# Mass loss rate in a typical visible-from-Earth comet

Tags: comets

What is the typical range of a comet's mass loss per second to its dust and gas tails, while it is naked-eye visible from Earth?

I'm aware this is going to be a very broad range and expect it to cover multiple orders of magnitude, so any specific examples — Hale–Bopp, Halley's, or similar, at any point where their apparent magnitude was enough to be visible without a telescope — would be perfectly valid answers, even though I'm mainly curious about the minimum.

[Target level: I'm an amateur enthusiast, not a professional].

Comment: [Comets lose mass with each passage through the inner solar system ...](https://www.vanderbilt.edu/AnS/physics/astrocourses/AST101/readings/comets.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no typical value. If you insist, use about 1kg/s but allow deviations of at least 2 orders or magnitude, depending on comet, Earth distance etc. One can make reasonable deductions from observations of the comets in the last 35 years.

[M. Choukroun et al](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11214-020-00662-1.pdf). and cited sources therein estimate the mass loss rate of 67/P Churyumov-Gerasimenko at around $10^{28}$ molecules/s at peak mass loss and an overall around $10^{10}$ kg (corresponding to ~1kg/s) during the whole perihelion passage over the course of the 2 years.
[Moreno et al](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231066154_Dust_in_Comet_67PChuryumov-Gerasimenko) give dust loss rates around 1 to 1000 kg/s during perihelion passage. [G. C. Sanzovo et al](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249430465_Mass-loss_rates_dust_particle_sizes_nuclear_active_areas_and_minimum_nuclear_radii_of_target_comets_for_missions_STARDUST_and_CONTOURP). do a comparative study for a number of recent bright comets and get similar numbers.

There exists an old study from 1987 by [Kresak, L. & Kresakova, M.](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1987ESASP.278..739K) which estimates the mass loss rates for many comets per century giving values between $10^8$ and $10^{12}$ kg / century (higher end is Halley) - which generally are not too far off of what is quoted above, but take these values with a grain of salt as far fewer in-situ measurments to calibrate models were available by then and science on comets has progressed a lot since.